# How can I template with container only?

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I dont think my title is accurate so just go to the code.

```
namespace Fobaizer
{
  template <typename T, typename C>
  static T GetItemFromContainer(const C &container) {
    T item = container[0]; // do something. 0 or iterator
    return item;
  }
}
```

Example:

```
MyClass myClass = Fobaizer::GetItemFromContainer<MyClass, vector<MyClass>(myVector);
```

or

```
MyClass myClass = Fobaizer::GetItemFromContainer<MyClass, deque<MyClass>(myDeque);
```

Here C is any container like `std::deque` or `std::vector`. I search for a C98 solution without any lib (boost, QT, etc.)

In fact, I am looking for something like the `IEnumerable` of C#.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: The code is not clear enough. `C` is a type; you can't `C[0]`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Oh sorry. I missed something. I will edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename C>
static typename C::value_type GetItemFromContainer(const C & container) {
    typename C::value_type item = container[0]; // do something. 0 or iterator
    return item;
 }
```

Basically every container defines the member typedefs:

```
 value_type
 reference
 const_reference
 iterator
 const_iterator
```

So you can just use `C::value_type` if you want to return by value, `C::reference` if you want to return by reference, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a test that checks whether you can call `std::begin` and `std::end` on your container.  And then use iterators to those containers and `std::advance` to advance your iterators to where you need them.

The advantage of this method is then you can accept containers that don't overload `operator[]` (like `std::list` for example)

```
    #include <utility>
    #include <type_traits>
    #include <vector>
    #include <list>

    namespace sfinae_true_details
    {
        template <class>
        struct sfinae_true : std::true_type{};
    }

    template <class T>
    auto test_has_begin_end(int) ->
        sfinae_true_details::sfinae_true<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()) ==
                                                  std::end(std::declval<T>())>;        

    template <class>
    std::false_type test_has_begin_end(long);

    template <class T>
    struct has_begin_end : decltype(test_has_begin_end<T>(0)){};

    int main()
    {
        static_assert(has_begin_end<std::vector<int> >::value, "");
        static_assert(has_begin_end<std::list<float> >::value, "");
        static_assert(has_begin_end<int>::value, "Expected to fail here");
        return 0;
    }
```

Then your usage would be:

```
      template <typename T, typename C>
      static T GetItemFromContainer(const C &container) {
          static_assert(has_begin_end<C>::value, "Must pass a container for which "
                        "std::begin and std::end are callable");
          T item = *std::begin(container); // do something. 0 or iterator
          auto iter = std::begin(container);
          std::advance(iter, 5);
          item = *iter; // equivalent to container[5] for RandomAccessContainers
          return item;
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for info. By the way, I cant use c++11.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do IEnumerable in C++, iterator is a good choice to iterate a collection.

Comment: An IEnumrable, is an interface implemented by every container/collection in C#. A container is something iterable so, yes I use iterator :)